# Reason for including the public key of the key agreement in the KDF

Tags: public-key, elliptic-curves, diffie-hellman, key-exchange, key-derivation

I found [the following text](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/255970196_Analysis_of_ECIES_and_other_Cryptosystems_based_on_Elliptic_Curves) when looking up KDFs:

> In comparison, the so-called DHAES mode in IEEE 1363a mandates to use the binary representation of the sender’s public key as an input parameter.

where a quick lookup suggests that DHES and DHAES are simply earlier names for ECIES.

What would be the reason to include the sender's public key into the KDF as a parameter? Other ECDH based schemes do not seem to do this.

If the sender's public key is altered then the calculated shared secret $Z$ would be invalid and the KDF would fail to generate the correct key anyway. Is this just an additional spurious security measure or am I missing some significant reasoning?

Comment: Can you put the link of the source?

Comment: @kelalaka Adjusted.

Comment: I suspect that the answer is in [this](https://www.shoup.net/papers/iso-2_1.pdf) or its references. But where?

Comment: I don't think so. I went through it entirely and found a statement that it doesn't use any parameters. That's not so strange as it defines the KDF1-4 without parameters as well. Can't speak of the references yet of course - as there are 25 I presume it is in there though - if not it will be in the references of the references :P.

Comment: I did a lot of looking into the references, but if it is there it has *still* escaped me.