# Is there value in performing signature during key exchange?

Tags: signature, protocol-design, key-exchange

I looked around the net, however I couldn't see anything authoritative on this.

If one is using something like libsodium to perform key exchange (using x25519), is there value in using Ed25519/signature, to sign the public keys being exchanged for use in the key agreement scheme (assuming the ed25519 keys are correctly tied to an entities identity)?

Or is this over-engineering?

I have static keyPairs tied to user identity in my app, and see some value in signature despite the extra effort to sign public keys being exchanged during symmetric key agreement.

Comment: You may be interested in [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/67290/reason-for-including-the-public-key-of-the-key-agreement-in-the-kdf) unfortunately unanswered for now. I guess it is hard to tell if things like these are indeed worth doing if the scheme can formally do without it.

Comment: There is definitely value in doing this: the DH keys can be ephemeral instead of being static, so you gain forward secrecy. Also, in interactive protocols, signatures may not be the only option for authentication. The [Noise protocol framework](http://www.noiseprotocol.org/), in particular, provides patterns leveraging the DH function for authentication.

Comment: As you can see from the comments, it is unclear what you really mean with the question. Are you asking if there is value in *signing the public keys*? Is there value in signing for authentication after or during key exchange? If you have a private key for authentication and a trusted public key then you have to sign *something* unique to the handshake, and I guess that could be an ephemeral public key (provided that you validate that the shared secret is correct afterwards, of course). Possibly this already answers your question?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I guess I was asking two things, 1) is it worth deliberately signing any distributed public keys with the static ed25519 keys (and I think the answer is yes), as once the ed25519 static pub keys have been distributed correctly we can use this approach to avoid MITM attack... and 2) as Frank Denis says, if I generate ephemeral curve25519 keys for each DH exchange, I can achieve forward secrecy with libsodium...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for the first question: as long as you create a signature over *some or all data* that is *required and unique* in the key establishment protocol then you should get entity authentication for that session. If you sign entire messages then you may be able to avoid some attacks on the message format itself. Some protocols deliberately include the public key into that calculation, others don't. Including the public key is not strictly required of course, you can also sign over a nonce used in the protocol or even over the shared secret (although I would seriously frown on the latter, as you don't want to use the key material for anything other than what it should be used for).

I'd also make sure that the established secret is correct by validating the generated secret (derive a MAC key and use that to create a MAC over *some or all* data unique to the session); you don't want to be relying on the messages themselves (implicit authentication) to verify the data and shared secret, use explicit authentication instead. It might be a good idea to start hashing the messages immediately and perform the signing / MAC'-ing over the calculated hash for maximum efficiency.

Yes, you can achieve forward secrecy with libsodium, if - as always - you make sure you destroy the keys as soon as they are not needed anymore. *Just* performing ephemeral-static DH - using whatever scheme - doesn't cut it, as you must make sure that the key material is not available anymore. Fortunately, Daniel is known for trying to make his protocol implementations in such a way that key destruction is easy.